# How to configure _oasis for OCaml to set 'Profile' flag

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

I have an existing project in OCaml and one `_oasis` file. I don't know where to enable the profiling flag for `ocamlbuild`.

I looked up Oasis manual and the code, and found there was a variable `profile` available in setup.data. I assume this was what Oasis auto generated.

Where and what should I include in _oasis to set `profile` to true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate the `ocamlbuild_more_args` feature.

On top of your `_oasis` file:

```
AlphaFeatures: ocamlbuild_more_args
```

Then, in your Package:

```
XOCamlbuildExtraArgs: your_ocamlbuild_option
```

I can't find any -profile option in ocamlbuild though, so I'm not sure of what this is about. Also, this option is still quite unstable.

A better way to handle that would be to modify your `_tags` file accordingly. It is generated by oasis but you can modify it.

EDIT:

`setup.data` informs you of environment variables. As for profile, it shows if the `-p` option will be passed to ocamlopt. You can pass it using the `NativeOpt` field.

Comment: `ocamlbuild` allows us to specify `ocamlc` options via `cflags`, but profile is an `ocamlopt` flag, not the `ocamlc` one, so we can't pass it through ocamlbuild. We can only rely on the set intersections of the `ocamlc` and `ocamlopt` options.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the oasis profile flag by adding the `--enable-profile` argument to the `./configure` flag. But so far, I have only noticed any effect when I enabled native code compilation (`CompiledObject: native` in _oasis). Even then, the profiling generation is only done for gprof.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `_tags` file as it is the easiest way. Just add the following to your `_tags`:

```
<true> : profile
```

You run this command:

```
echo "<true> : profile" >> _tags
```

in the folder where your `_tags` file is located.

If you still want to use `_oasis` file, then you can use `NativeOpt` field, to add options that will be passed to native compiler, i.e., `ocamlopt`.