# How to add -thread to _oasis to compile with Core

Tags: ocaml, oasis, ocaml-core

I've been using `oasis` to build my project using some external packages.  Now I also want to use Jane Street's Core package.  However, in order to compile with Core, you have to pass the `-thread` flag to `ocamlfind`, e.g. like this:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core foo.ml -o foo
```

How can I tell `oasis` to add the `-thread` flag?  Right now, my _oasis file includes something like the following:

```
Executable "foo"
  BuildDepends: core,batteries,bar
  Path: src
  MainIs: foo.ml
  CompiledObject: best
```

Bar a collection of my own utilities from the same project.  When I run `oasis setup` and `make`, I get this error:

```
ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
```

I looked at the Oasis manual, and neither the [common fields](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/MANUAL.html#common-fields) for all sections of the _oasis file, nor the [fields that are specific to the Excutable section](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/MANUAL.html#executable) seem to be appropriate for adding a command line flag for `ocamlfind`.

I  thought that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562387/1455243) might be relevant, but when I tried adding the extra keys it suggested, with `-thread` as the value for `XOCamlbuildExtraArgs`, I got an error:

```
E: Field XOCamlbuildExtraArgs is not defined in schema Executable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following line to your _tags file:

```
<**/*>: thread
```

There will be a bunch of stuff between the `OASIS_START` and `OASIS_STOP` delimiters, don't add anything between them, but rather before or after.

Comment: Thanks ivg.  That did the trick.  (_tags is automatically generated by `oasis setup` but doesn't get overwritten once it's generated, it seems, so this solution should work in general.)

Comment: For anyone else coming along, what I wrote in that comment was wrong.  _tags can be altered by `oasis setup`, but it leaves the additional line at the end as is.

Comment: I tried the above, with `BuildDepends: \n core`, in a very simple one-line “project”, but I'm getting: `Error: Files /usr/local/lib/ocaml/threads/threads.cmxa and /usr/local/lib/ocaml/threads/threads.cmxa both define a module named Thread` (yes, that's the same path twice … wtf?)